# Zend - Strange title behavior

Tags: php, zend-framework

'm seeing some really weird behavior with the headTitle() function.
My index page looks fine and it's showing the title of my project defined in my application.ini file.

However my site controllers are displaying some odd titles when being set on my controllers.

```
// [application.ini]
project.title = "Portal"

// [indexController.php]
$this->headTitle([project][title]); //  -> this results in title "Portal" which is correct

// [ControllerOne.php]
$this->headTitle('Today News', 'PREPEND'); //  -> this results in a title similar to "Today News - SomeOtherController - Today News - Portal" which is totally wrong and odd.
```

Any thoughts on why am i seeing that behaviour?
I ran a grep for headTitle on all of my project and everything looks correct to me. I also tried commenting out several of the headTitle() functions just to debug and still the same behavior.

Is this some kind of bug in the function? Does anyone have any debugging tips to solve this? This is my first project with zend and don't really know where else to look.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: What is ControllerOne.php? View, Model or some class?

Comment: All of my Controllers inherit Zend_Controller_Action

Comment: have you visited this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/521513/zend-framework-headtitle-append-issue

Comment: @AwaisQarni: yes. my question is not with the order in which items appear. my question is why is it using some other controllers title, it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: in which function do you call $this->headTitle...

Comment: @max4ever: in my init() functions for the controllers

Comment: @nmuntz Have you checked your layout? It can happen that in layout you have hardcoded some thing?

Comment: @AwaisQarni: yes, the layout is fine

Comment: @nmuntz Have u resolved this by now?

Comment: Are you using `forward()` in any actions which is resulting in another action being run?